# Recortar cadena de caracteres con vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net

alguien me podría decir como recortar una cadena de caracteres obteniendo el número X de caracteres y agregando `...` al final de la cadena en ASP.net

```
Dim cadenaOriginal As String = "Anita lava la tina."
Dim cadenaRecortada As String = "Anita lava..."
```

En ese caso se sustraen los primeros 10 caracteres de la cadena (contando el espacio)

Comment: Es muy sencillo. Has intentado algo? Revisa el método `SubString` de string

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que:

> En ese caso se sustraen los primeros 10 caracteres de la cadena

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
Imports System

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()

        Dim cadenaOriginal As String = "Anita lava la tina."
        Dim cadenaNueva As String = cadenaOriginal.Substring(0,10) + "..."
        Console.WriteLine(cadenaNueva)

    End Sub
End Module
```

Esto da como resultado:

```
Anita lava...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
' Pon esto al principio del archivo fuera del Modulo
imports vb = Microsoft.VisualBasic

' Dentro de las funciones que has incorporado tienes las Funciones 
 Dim Cadena1 = vb.Left(Cadena,NumCaracteres) as String
 Dim Cadena2 = vb.Right(Cadena,NumCaracteres) as String
```

'El Idioma es Visual Basic.NET
'El Imports vb = Microsoft.VisualBasic Se Pone Fuera de las Clases
'Y Las funciones de abajo devuelven una Variable Son Así y han de ir en las 'Sub y Functions de Tu Programa en VB.NET

Dim cadenaOriginal As String = vb.Left("Este es el Ejemplo",4)
MsgBox(cadenaOriginal)

Espero que te sirva...

Comment: Esto no soluciona el problema que tiene el OP, y tampoco estas explicando que hace el código que has puesto como respuesta. Intenta formular buenas respuestas ya que no es la primera tuya que tiene este formato.

Comment: El Idioma es Visual Basic.NET
El Imports vb = Microsoft.VisualBasic Se Pone Fuera de las Clases
Y Las funciones de abajo devuelven una Variable Son Así y han de ir en las Sub y Functions de Tu Programa en VB.NET

Dim cadenaOriginal As String = vb.Left("Este es el Ejemplo",4)
MsgBox(cadenaOriginal)